# Responsive triangles in a horizontal rule

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to create a fancy geometric looking horizontal rule. It consists of two triangles the points of which meet at the center of the page.

Below is a hacky code snippet showing what I've achieved so far. My issue is that it isn't responsive, I need the width of the triangles to span 50% of the window width. Plus I shuddered when I had to use `calc`.

The only way I can think about achieving what I want is to make the border width massive, then stick an `overflow-x: hidden;` on the container, but I'm sure there must be a better way to do this. Potentially using some sort of `skew`?

```css
hr {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
hr:before {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 200px 0 0;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 200px);
  top: 25px;
}
hr:after {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 50px 200px;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use the `vw` unit for the `border-width`. `vw` is relative to the width of the viewport which means that border will adapt as the viewport width is increased/decreased. To ensure the triangle keeps the same shape the top/bottom borders can be modified to use `vw` units, this will ensure that the triangle's `height` is relative to it's `width`.

Rather than use `margin` a `height` equal to the `height` of the two triangles can be used for the `hr`, this makes it easier to position the triangles and ensures enough space is allotted for them (so they don't overlap other elements).

To achieve this the following modifications are required:

- Remove `margin: 50px 0;` from `hr`
- Add `height: 16vw;` to `hr`
- Change `border-width: 50px 200px 0 0;` to `border-width: 8vw 25vw 0 0;`, `top: 25px;` to `bottom: 0;` and `left: calc(50% - 200px);` to `right: 50%;` on `hr:before`
- Change `border-width: 0 0 50px 200px;` to `border-width: 0 0 8vw 25vw;` and `top: -25px;` to `top: 0;` on `hr:after`

```css
hr {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 16vw;
}

hr:before {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8vw 25vw 0 0;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}

hr:after {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 8vw 25vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```